# How to disable window service when the service doesn't accept SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP control code?

Tags: windows, windows-services, terminal-services

Actually, I trying to disable terminal service in windows XP.

But this service doesn't accept any control code. even SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN.

I can't disable it in system control panel, using net stop termservice, sc stop termservice.

So now I'm trying to execute freelibrary(termservice) in svchost using remote thread injection.

Is there any better idea?!

Thanks for reading :]

Comment: Are you trying to disable it or stop it?  You should be able to change the service configuration to disabled, and the next time you reboot the system it will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

Correct; [none of those are the documented way to disable Terminal Services](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=278657).

Instead, do [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776276.aspx):

> #### Switching Terminal Services on and off
>
> To disable Terminal Services connections temporarily (for example, to install an application on a terminal server), go to the **Remote** tab in System Properties and clear the **Allow users to connect remotely to your computer** checkbox. (This checkbox is cleared by default when you install any of the Windows Server 2003 family operating systems.) When you disable remote connections, Terminal Services remains active on the computer, but no new remote connections are accepted.
>
> If Terminal Server is installed on your computer, you can also uninstall it by using **Add or Remove programs**. When you do so, the computer is returned to its default state, Remote Desktop for Administration.

(I assume you're talking about Windows Server 2003, since I believe that "Terminal Services" was renamed to "Remote Desktop Services" in later versions.)

Comment: He's talking about Windows XP.  The Terminal Services service provides support for Remote Desktop and for Fast User Switching and as of XP is present in both client and server editions of Windows.  It is related to but not identical to the Terminal Services (now Remote Desktop Services) feature which is available only in Windows Server products.

Answer (score 0):

You must turn off "Fast User Switching".